# Swapping numbers before and after decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point

I'm writing a function that takes a **positive number** and swaps the numbers before and after the decimal point and returns that as a **string**. If the input is an integer then the returned string starts with '0.' i.e. 37 -> 0.37

```py
def float_swap(x):
    a = x - int(x)
    b = int(x)
    return str(b+a)

print(float_swap(2.5))
# 2.5
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Simplify the equation a bit - what does `int(x) + x - int(x)` equal? You may want to do this as a string operation rather than a math operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the comments I put in your code to better understand what is happening:

```
def float_swap(x): # 2.5
    a = x - int(x) # a = 2.5 - 2 = 0.5
    b = int(x)     # b = 2
    return str(b+a)# str(2 + 0.5)

print(float_swap(2.5))
# 2.5
```

The correct way would be

```
def float_swap(x): # 2.5
    return '.'.join(str(float(x)).split('.')[::-1])

print(float_swap(2.5))
print(float_swap(37))
```

Output:

```
5.2
0.37
```

Comment: @cdlane Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is given in previous answers.
If you are interested about the solution you can do the following:

```
def float_swap(x):
    s=str(float(x))
    return s[s.find('.')+1:]+'.'+ s[:s.find('.')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to split the values before and after the decimal, I'd suggest typecasting as a string, then splitting using '.' as your delimiter. Then swapping the two values and returning the result when adding together. Below is an example

```
def float_swap(x):
    a = float(x)
    a, b = str(a).split('.')
    return b + '.' + a
```

Then `float_swap(2)` returns `0.2`

Answer (score 1):

```
def swap(num):
  num = str(float(num))
  a, b = num.split('.')
  res = b + '.' + a
  return res


print(swap(2)) # 0.2
print(swap(21.34)) # 34.21
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not swap.

Change it to

```
def float_swap(x):
    ix = int(x)
    if x == ix:
        return f"0.{ix}"
    return '.'.join(str(x).split(".")[::-1])

print(float_swap(2.5))

print(float_swap(37))
```

Output:

```
5.2
0.37
```

or convert x to float everytime, so if you get a `37` as input you make it `37.0` and you can remove the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Python3 *fstring*, I think we might be able to make this simpler:

```
def float_swap(x):
    return f"{x % 1 * 10:.0f}.{x:.0f}"

print(float_swap(2.5))
print(float_swap(37))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
5.2
0.37
>
```